# Dropbox Chooser to upload files from user's dropbox account

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

Hi I am implementing the functionality in which users can upload pictures from their dropbox account. For that I found Dropbox Chooser, which helps to upload the files form our dropbox account. Following is the code, used dropbox chooser documentation. When I click on button, it supposed to open the window with the dropbox login screen. I get the dropbox screen but with the message 'Sorry for this little hiccups.... please try to relaod the page'. I found some similar problems forums and followed their solutions. Ofcourse, none worked. Any help is appreciated and would be great. TIA

**Index.php**

```
<div id="dropbox-upload-container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="wgiv8kvzvq57mlw"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    options = {
        success: function(files) {
            files.forEach(function(file) {
            // add_img_to_list(file);
            });
        },
        cancel: function() {
          //optional
        },
        linkType: "preview", // "preview" or "direct"
        multiselect: true, // true or false
        extensions: ['.png', '.jpg'],
    };

    var button = Dropbox.createChooseButton(options);
    document.getElementById("dropbox-upload-container").appendChild(button);

</script>
```

Comment: In your actual setup, do you have `#my-app-key` replaced with your app key? Also, make sure you don't have the `#` included. It should be only your alphanumeric app key string.

Comment: I have my original app-key in my actual code, `#my-app-key` is just for here.

Comment: And just to be clear, you don't have the "#" in the app key value in your actual code right?

Comment: Yes, I don't have '#' sign too in my original code.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. I can't reproduce this issue using this code (with an app key plugged in without the "#") though. Do you have a live sample page that reproduces the issue that you can share? If not, please [open an API ticket](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact) with the steps to reproduce the issue so we can look into it.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for helping still. I added my app-key in the question, if that can help you to find out ? And I don't have live version yet.

Comment: Thanks! I believe we tracked this down to an issue in the error handling on our side. To avoid it, make sure you register your "Chooser/Saver domains" on [the App Console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps).

Comment: If I am using on localhost what should I write in my Chooser domain ?

Comment: Worked. Thanks man. I appreciate it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Can avoid this error by setting the html page with in the server. For this purpose, I used express - node.js.

Following is the snippet:
**finaltest.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "finaltest.html" );
})

var server = app.listen(8081)
```

For html, js : https://codepen.io/sreepurna/pen/NYmMaj

Now run the server - **node finaltest.js**

Go to the web browser and use http://localhost:8081.

Hope this helps!!!!